# How do I update data from multiple traces in plotly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly

I have a set of pair of graphs that I'd like to plot in the same figure. Each graph correspond to a `go.Scatter` object. In plotly, I'm trying to use the `go.Layout.updatemenus` argument to build a dropdown menu that allows to select which pair of graphs I'd like to plot.

When I select a new pair, I have to update the data in the two `go.Scatter` objects, and also in the `go.Layout` object. I've tried to do as follows, but it didn't work.

```py
    trace1 = go.Scatter(
       x = x_data1,
       y = y_data1,
       name = name1,
       mode = 'markers',
       marker = dict(
           size = 2
       )
    )

    trace2 = go.Scatter(
       x = x_data1,
       y = y_data1,
       name = name2,
       mode = 'lines',
       line = dict(
           color = 'Red',
           width = 3
       )
    )

    buttons_list = []
    for key in dictio.keys():
        buttons_list.append(dict(
                            label=key,
                            method='update',
                            args=[{"x": dictio[key].xdata1,
                                   "y": dictio[key].ydata1,
                                   "name": key},
                                  {"x":dictio[key].xdata2,
                                   "y":dictio[key].ydata2},
                                  {"annotations": get_annotations(key)}
                            ]
                        )
        )
    updatemenus = list([
        dict(
            active=0,
            buttons=buttons_list,
            direction='down',
            x = 0.05,
            xanchor='left',
            y = 1,
            yanchor='top'
        )         
    ])

    layout = go.Layout(
        updatemenus = updatemenus,
        annotations = annotations,
    )

    fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
    plot(fig, auto_open=True)
```

Comment: did you ever find any solution for this problem? 